# PySpark read in multiple files for processing with limited RAM

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a bunch of raw data in multiple JSON files (on Azure Blob Storage). I tried doing `spark.read.json()` which seem to work but very slow ... I wonder if theres a way to read in files one by one for processing?

My processing is just filtering, I want to omit certain attributes and transform data like split strings and cast into numbers for example.

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, lower, unix_timestamp, from_unixtime

rawQuestionsDf = spark.read.json("wasb://....blob.core.windows.net/pquestionsjson/datajson%2F*.json")

questionsDf = rawQuestionsDf.select('id', 'title', 'tags', 'owner_user_id', 'accepted_answer_id', 'view_count',
                       'answer_count', 'comment_count', 'creation_date', 'favorite_count') \
    .withColumn('tags', split(df['tags'], '\|')) \
    .withColumn('title', lower(df['title'])) \
    .withColumn('view_count', df['view_count'].cast('integer')) \
    .withColumn('answer_count', df['answer_count'].cast('integer')) \
    .withColumn('comment_count', df['comment_count'].cast('integer')) \
    .withColumn('favorite_count', df['favorite_count'].cast('integer')) \
    .withColumn('creation_date', df['creation_date'])

questionsDf.write.parquet("wasb://data@cs4225.blob.core.windows.net/filtered/questions.parquet")
```

I wonder if theres a better way? would `wholeTextFile` be a better choice?

Comment: a) Don't use schema inference b) In general avoid wildcards when working with object stores.

Comment: @user8371915 What's the reason behind avoiding wildcards when working with object stores?

Comment: @user8371915 I understand now schema inference will affect performance, but in this case, how do I specify the types? And for (b), what are you refering to? Isit `datajson%2F*.json` part?

Comment: @JiewMeng It is not possible to say without seeing the data, but nce you know the schema, which has been inferred, you can use it right away by passing it to `DataFrameReader.schema`  method. By wildcard I mean `*`. It might not make much of a difference, but it is usually behaves less than optimally (details vary on store basis).